# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del led al lanzar una notificación?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Estoy intentado encender el led del smartphone cuando lanzo una notificación. El problema es que el color que me muestra es siempre azul y no respeta los tiempos de apagado y encendido del led. 
Este es mi código:

```
if (textoEstado.equals("Alarma"))
    {
        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(-1)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(texto)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLights(0xFFFF00, 1, 1)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources()                            
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.logoriegosalz)).getBitmap()))
                .addAction(icono_r, null, contentIntent)
 .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .build();

    }else if (textoEstado.equals("Abierto"))
    {
        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(-1)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(texto)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLights(0xFF0000FF, 1, 1)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources()                            
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.logoriegosalz)).getBitmap()))
                .addAction(icono_r, null, contentIntent)
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .build();

    }else
    {
        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(-1)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(texto)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLights(0xFF00FF00, 1, 1)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.logoriegosalz)).getBitmap()))
                .addAction(icono_r, null, contentIntent)
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .build();
    }

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, titulo, texto, contentIntent);

    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Me entra a los diferentes if, eso no es problema, pero no me respeta el color del led ni el tiempo que le indico

Comment: Revisa tu lógica si es que debe encenderse otro color, en cuanto a la falla elimina .setDefaults(-1)

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, si quito el .setDefaults(-1) ni siquiera me enciende los led :(

Answer (score 1):

Para encender el Led se usa el método [setLights()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLights(int,%20int,%20int)) , debes tomar en cuenta el tiempo que indicas este encendido y el tiempo apagado.

Como ejemplo, enciende el led con color verde, se mantiene 1 segundo encendido y 5 segundos apagado:

```
mBuilder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 1000, 5000);
```

---

Revisa la lógica de tu código, si tu led se enciende de color azul, significa que esta entrando en :

```
 .setLights(0xFF0000FF, 1, 1)
```

**Elimina [setDefaults()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)) que es lo que seguramente esta evitando se encienda el led.**

```
.setDefaults(-1)
```

Comment: He estado mirando y ni me respeta los tiempos que le pongo ni el color y no es por que me entre al azul, porque me entra bien a los 3 casos, incluso si en los 3 casos le pongo rojo (para hacer pruebas) la luz me sale azul y aunque cambie los tiempos me realiza el parpadeo siempre igual. Además si le quito el setDefault ni siquiera me ilumina los led.

Comment: He vuelto a comprobarlo y si quito el setDefault ni siquiera me enciende los led...